# How to install all required plugin when installing theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to create a theme that install all required plugins when installing theme,basically I want to add all my required plug ins to the theme when I install theme all plugins install by default,how I can do this?
I have search but can not get solution to do this.

Comment: Because it's a terrible question.

Comment: @GordonM,so should i do ?its possible or not?

Comment: You should Googling before make a question.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/) is a an article that will explain how to install required plugins when installing a theme (found by Googling: [install required plugin when installing a theme](https://www.google.com/search?q=install%20required%20plugin%20when%20installing%20a%20theme&oq=install%20required%20plugin%20when%20installing%20a%20them):

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins). It allows your users to install and even automatically activate plugins in singular or bulk fashion using native WordPress classes, functions and interfaces. You can reference pre-packaged plugins, plugins from the WordPress Plugin Repository or even plugins hosted elsewhere on the internet.

Some of the options include:

- name - The name of the plugin.
- slug - The plugin slug, which is typically the name of the folder that holds the plugin.
  required - Either true or false. If set to true, the plugin is "required". If set to false, the plugin is "recommended".
- source - The source of the plugin. This parameter is required if the plugin you are referencing is not from the WordPress Plugin Repository. You can reference either pre-packaged plugins or plugins elsewhere on the internet from this parameter.

Following that example should be able to achieve what you are looking for.